# How do you allow time entry in 2 formats in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want users to be able to entry time as `decimals`:

`8.25`

and as `time`:

`8:15`

What Django FormField should I use?

My thoughts are to make is a `forms.CharField()` as that would remove HTML restrictions and `forms.TimeField()` creates the same input.

What Validators should be applied to that formfield?

I'm not sure if I need to create a custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CharField` with custom validation in `clean_fieldname` method:

```
class TimeForm(forms.Form):
    user_time = forms.CharField()

    def clean_time_field(self):
        user_time = self.cleaned_data['user_time']
        if '.' in user_time:
            hours, minutes = user_time.split('.')
        elif ':' in user_time:
            hours, minutes = user_time.split(':')
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Provide correct time')
        return datetime.time(hour=hours, minute=minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible approaches and which is the best one depends on many other things in your project.

How do you save the time in your database? Do you use `models.TimeField()`? Do you denormalize - save the value also in `models.DecimalField()`?

Can you use JavaScript in the templates? If yes, I'd go with a dynamic form that allows user interaction. Maybe something like this:

```
<label for="timeformat_switcher"
<input type="checkbox" id="timeformat_switcher">Enter a decimal value
</label>

<input type="time" id="time">
<input type="number" id="number"><!-- make it per default in CSS hidden -->
```

When the user checks the checkbox hide the `<input type="time">` with JavaScript and unhide the `<input type="number">`.
Use also JavaScript to convert the decimal value to time and send it to the server.

Comment: It is stored as a `DecimalField` in the db. I would prefer the conversion take place server side.

Comment: @surfer190 Could you please give a short explanation why do use `DecimalField` for storing time instead of `TimeField`?

Comment: It is easier to work with...addition, multiplication, subtraction works better

Comment: @surfer190 Why do you need those operations? What do you want to actually store: time like 17:30 (5:30pm) or amount of hours (duration) like 17 hours and 30 minutes?